# Does the pythonic os.sched_yield() release the GIL?

Tags: release, cpython, gil

I've found this question about GIL released by modules: [Does who releases GIL in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73104175/does-who-releases-gil-in-python)
I was looking for the `os.sched_yield()` implementation and I can't see the GIL release macro or function:

```c
/*[clinic input]
os.sched_yield
Voluntarily relinquish the CPU.
[clinic start generated code]*/

static PyObject *
os_sched_yield_impl(PyObject *module)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=902323500f222cac input=e54d6f98189391d4]*/
{
    if (sched_yield())
        return posix_error();
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

(from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cfaa79aac088284c1eeacddc19ddebe06b55dcf7/Modules/posixmodule.c#L7060)

I think it would be ridiculous not to release the GIL while calling `sched_yield()`. Is it released anywhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it was an issue - GIL hasn't been released, but should be. The bug is there since the function was implemented, 11 years ago.
More info on the issue: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/96078